# Create Cross(X) Button dynamically with each Edit Text View that I am creating dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

What I am doing is, I am creating Edit Text Views on click of a button. What i want is, as soon as, a Edit Text View appears a small button will also gets appears to its right(having (X) image(so, that i can delete that particular Edit Text View). I am able to generate Edit Text Views but have no idea regarding the button creation.Please guide or help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new button the same way as the EditText view with an x in it an align it to the right of the EditText field, and then do an onclicklistener on the button that will call to the db or whatever you are using to remove the actual text and then you can remove both the view and edit button from the layout. However, from the code you provided I do not see anything in regards to a onClickListener being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation

```
<CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000" />
```

where `ic_action_cancel` is `x` icon.
and following is the custom Edittext class

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    private Drawable drawableRight;
    int actionX, actionY;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
            Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        if (right != null) {
            drawableRight = right;
        }
        super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Rect bounds;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            actionX = (int) event.getX();
            actionY = (int) event.getY();
            // this works for left since container shares 0,0 origin with bounds
            if (drawableRight != null) {
                bounds = null;
                bounds = drawableRight.getBounds();
                int x, y;
                int extraTapArea = 13;
                int extraTapArea = 20;
                x = (int) (actionX + extraTapArea);
                y = (int) (actionY - extraTapArea);
                x = getWidth() - x;
                if (x <= 0) {
                    x += extraTapArea;
                }
                if (y <= 0)
                    y = actionY;
                if (bounds.contains(x, y)) {
                    setText("");
                    return false;
                }
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```